# Color entire rows in a table without a border

Tags: html, css

is it possible to color entire rows in an html table without being a "break" or gap for the border?

So far I have this table:

```
<table width="500px">
    <tr bgcolor="pink">
        <td>Nombre blog</td>
        <td>Autora</td>
        <td>Idioma</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The Blonde Salad</td>
        <td>Chiara Ferragni</td>
        <td>Italiano</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
       <td>The Pioneer Woman</td>
        <td>Ree Drummond</td>
        <td>Inglés</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>La Tartine Gourmande</td>
        <td>Béatrice Peltre</td>
        <td>Francés</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
       <td>Objetivo Cupcake Perfecto</td>
        <td>Alma Obregón</td>
        <td>Español</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncsmzmch/

As you can see there is a white gap between columns. If I put a border or even a collapsed border, that gap obviously dissapears, cause it's filled by the line (border).

But I want to leave the rows colored, but all in one line, without the gaps, and no borders.

Can that be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to stay away from those attributes. They're all [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)...

Answer (score 11):

Sure, add a [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) rule:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncsmzmch/1/)**

```css
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table width="500px">
    <tr bgcolor="pink">
        <td>Nombre blog</td>
        <td>Autora</td>
        <td>Idioma</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The Blonde Salad</td>
        <td>Chiara Ferragni</td>
        <td>Italiano</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
        <td>The Pioneer Woman</td>
        <td>Ree Drummond</td>
        <td>Inglés</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>La Tartine Gourmande</td>
        <td>Béatrice Peltre</td>
        <td>Francés</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
        <td>Objetivo Cupcake Perfecto</td>
        <td>Alma Obregón</td>
        <td>Español</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Aww thanks so much j09691, I did tried that but didnt realized could be used without a border. So it collapsed my border instead of leaving it like a doubled border, but where was a still a line. Feel so silly now! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Do not forget to put it as the answer. This is for rewarding the person who helped you

Answer (score 1):

use cellspacing

```
<table width="500px" cellspacing=0>
<tr bgcolor="pink">
    <td>Nombre blog</td>
    <td>Autora</td>
    <td>Idioma</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>The Blonde Salad</td>
    <td>Chiara Ferragni</td>
    <td>Italiano</td>
</tr>
 <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
   <td>The Pioneer Woman</td>
    <td>Ree Drummond</td>
    <td>Inglés</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>La Tartine Gourmande</td>
    <td>Béatrice Peltre</td>
    <td>Francés</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
   <td>Objetivo Cupcake Perfecto</td>
    <td>Alma Obregón</td>
    <td>Español</td>
</tr>
```

see fiddle: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wtwt/ncsmzmch/3/)

Comment: I used the old html tags, like in your example. You better should use css codes to set your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, you can use one of two ways: either **cellspacing** or **border-collapse**:

```
table {
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

..or:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

Have fun!

Comment: Use `border-collapse`. `cellspacing` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)...

Comment: You're right, border-collapse is really better but for now both ways are working.

Answer (score 1):

Use border-spacing property and set it to 0 so that the gap is removed.

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;   
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0
}
```

```html
<table width="500px">
  <tr bgcolor="pink">
    <td>Nombre blog</td>
    <td>Autora</td>
    <td>Idioma</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The Blonde Salad</td>
    <td>Chiara Ferragni</td>
    <td>Italiano</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
    <td>The Pioneer Woman</td>
    <td>Ree Drummond</td>
    <td>Inglés</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>La Tartine Gourmande</td>
    <td>Béatrice Peltre</td>
    <td>Francés</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="mistyrose">
    <td>Objetivo Cupcake Perfecto</td>
    <td>Alma Obregón</td>
    <td>Español</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```